# Eclispe/STS terminates the maven program without output in console

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven-2

I am using Eclipse/STS with Maven and also pointing eclipse/sts maven path to local direcotry for my artifacts repository. However, when I run or debug the maven project, it gets terminate without any output on console, also other team member are using same setup of maven in eclipse/sts but they do not face any such problem. When I run the project from command prompt it run fine without any problem.

Is there any solution for this, I have tried in eclipse and STS and facing same problem. I would appreciate your inputs.

Comment: How do you run the project? Does the console set to your app "display selected console" tab? Have you also tried with a fresh (different) workspace? Does the problems tag contain any errors?

Comment: @helospark I am running project from run configuration, yes it display selected console tab, yes I have tried with fresh workspace, there is no errors...

Comment: Note that I am using Jbehave with Maven, rest assured and selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using maven which is not compatible with STS/Eclipse due to which it was terminating the program immidiatly after running!!!